# Are nebulae colored?

Tags: physics, ophthalmology, astronomy

The pictures of nebulae are always depicted as vividly colored and with a great variety of colors:

[image: Omega nebula] [Source](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/Omega_Nebula.jpg/296px-Omega_Nebula.jpg)
<sup>Omega nebula</sup>

[image: Eagle nebula pillars] [Source](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eagle_nebula_pillars.jpg)
<sup>Eagle nebula pillars</sup>

According to the [English wikipedia article on nebulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula), under the section [Formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula#Formation), *«as the material collapses under its own weight, massive stars may form in the center, and their ultraviolet radiation ionizes the surrounding gas, **making it visible at optical wavelengths**.»*

This means that we can see the nebulae, but not whether we see them colored or not.

Furthermore, in [this article](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2012/01/omega-nebula/) on Wired.com, there is a photograph of the Omega Nebula, which states: *«Looking more like a painting than an astronomy photograph, the Omega nebula glows with vivid colors in this new image from the European Southern Observatory’s Very Large Telescope. [...] The heart of the Omega nebula contains roughly 35 stars, the hottest of which spew out ultraviolet radiation that causes the surrounding hydrogen gas to glow red and pink.»*

On another site, [seasky.org](http://www.seasky.org/celestial-objects/nebulae.html), the article states: *«They are also among the most beautiful objects in the universe, glowing with rich colors and swirls of light. Stars inside these clouds of gas cause them to glow with beautiful reds, blues, and greens.»*

What I want to know is: if we could observe directly these nebulae, either by telescope or with our own eyes, would they appear like this? If not, how?

Comment: I can't add the tag [nebulae] due to my reputation. Can someone add it, please?

Comment: how about "vividly colored"?

Comment: +1 I've also heard that the color of Mars in rover-based photographs doesn't quite match what a human observer standing on Mars would see.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Thanks! How would it appear? Maybe less red?

Comment: @Alenanno sorry, but I can't remember.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm No problem! :)

Comment: They surely look pretty though!

Comment: Hmm... You ask if they are colored, but then you qualify the question with `would they appear like this?` The result, for me, is that the selected answer says no to the whole question of color, which is incorrect.  Simply because the Hubble uses black and white sensors, does not mean the color information is not available.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake The answer states that the colors we see are just post-processing effects applied to the different types of radiation. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Alenanno The colors we see in those particular images are. But that is not what the Title question asks.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake My question asked "are nebulae colored in reality as we see them in pictures?", the answer said "no". I don't see the problem, sorry.

Comment: I wasn't able to post the following question `Do nebulae emit light in the visible spectrum that we would associate with color?` because the title is already taken.

Comment: Is this really a question for Skeptics? You're not challenging a claim. This is more about you know knowing the answer to a simple scientific principle. This seems better suited to the Astronomy site... maybe.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Although it's not a clear-cut claim, I think that the pictures being spread around work a little this way. I myself discovered this some time ago; I came here to gain some "proof" on that. If the moderators think it's not a good question for the site, I'll abide by the decision.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I included two articles (thanks to Sklivvz's help) that don't mention whether the nebulae are really colored or not, and actually seem to suggest that they are.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From **[HubbleSite - Behind The Pictures](http://hubblesite.org/gallery/behind_the_pictures/)**:

### The Meaning of Color

> [image: Meaning of Color]
>
> **The colors in Hubble images, which are assigned for various reasons, aren't always what we'd see if we were able to visit the imaged objects in a spacecraft**.
>
> We often use color as a tool, whether it is to enhance an object's detail or to visualize what ordinarily could never be seen by the human eye.

### Example: The Eagle Nebula

> [image: Eagle Nebula]
>
> **Note:**
>
> The three B&W images each correspond to a certain wavelength (=color).
>
> > [image: Three Colors]
>
> - **Left**: Oxygen - Green
> - **Middle**: Hydrogen - Red
> - **Right**: Sulfur - Red
>
> Each of these B&W images are then (re-)assigned a unique color, *because otherwise the red light from hydrogen and that from sulfur would be hard to tell apart.*

### Choosing Colors

> [image: Color as a Tool]

### Why are the inital images B&W?

> The digital camera you have at home basically works the same way: [Light is "converted" into electrons.](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cameras-photography/digital/question362.htm)
>
> From [Panasonic](http://panasonic.jp/support/global/cs/dsc/knowhow/knowhow29.html):
>
> > **Since a [CCD](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cameras-photography/digital/question362.htm) can only distinguish whether light is strong or weak, color filters are used to obtain each color's light and dark information.**
>
> [image: RGB]
>
> (*I modified the above picture to make it more clear*)
>
> One can see that the *yellow* flower emits more in *red* and *green* (light) and less in *blue* (dark).
>
> [image: RGB] [[**RGB Color Model** on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)]

### Hubble's Color Filters

> Hubble uses special filters to "screen out" the types of light from an object that astronomers are not currently studying.
>
> **These filters allow only a certain range of light wavelengths through.** Once the unwanted light has been filtered out, **the resulting light is allowed to fall onto one or more light-sensitive detectors.**
>
> [image: Spec Wheel]
>
> **This produces a "picture" of the star in the selected wavelength.**
>
> Since the detectors can detect light outside the visible light spectrum, the use of filters allows scientists to see "invisible" objects — those only visible in ultraviolet and infrared wavelengths.
>
> [[Source](http://hubblesite.org/the_telescope/nuts_.and._bolts/spec101.php)]

### Example: The Eagle Nebula

> [image: M16]
>
> (**Source:** [ESA](http://sci.esa.int/science-e/www/object/index.cfm?fobjectid=49866))

### The Eagle Nebula in Visible Light (Wide Angle)

> [image: M16 visible]
>
> Three-colour (blue, green, red) composite mosaic image of the Eagle Nebula (Messier 16, or NGC 6611), based on images obtained with the [wide-field camera on the MPG/ESO 2.2 m-diameter telescope at the La Silla Observatory](http://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/lasilla/instruments/wfi/).
>
> At the centre, the *Pillars of Creation* can be seen.
>
> This wide-field image shows not only the central pillars, but also several others in the same star-forming region, as well as a huge number of stars in front of, in and behind the Eagle Nebula.
>
> (**Source:** [ESA](http://sci.esa.int/science-e/www/object/index.cfm?fobjectid=49868))

**More**

- [Slate - How Do Space Pictures Get So Pretty?](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2005/06/how_do_space_pictures_get_so_pretty.html)
- [Space.com - Truth Behind the Photos: What the Hubble Space Telescope Really Sees](http://www.space.com/8059-truth-photos-hubble-space-telescope-sees.html)
- [Universe Today - True or False (Color): The Art of Extraterrestrial Photography](http://www.universetoday.com/11863/true-or-false-color-the-art-of-extraterrestrial-photography/)

Comment: What would make this a killer answer would be *natural color* photos of the Omega and Eagle nebulas for comparison. Anyone?

Comment: @Oddthinking The "visible" light images in the above seem to be what you're asking for, no?

Comment: @Larry: Yes, Oliver stepped up after my comment and expanded his answer. I had already upvoted it, so to upvote him again, I've had to use a special supervote (you may need a custom camera to see it - it only emits in ultraviolet wavelengths.)

Comment: A “tl;dr: **Yes**.” sentence at the top would be *very* helpful …

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think the answer says that usually they are grayscale (with some pale coloring) and the differences in gas/radiations are used to color them.

Comment: @Alenanno And this is exactly why I’d like the “tl;dr” – because they are *not* grayscale at all. They are colour, and you (and probably many others) misunderstand that from this answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Look at the "paragraph" **Color as a tool**. There are three pictures: "natural", "representative" and "enhanced". I don't think it says yes. Nor that they are only gray. The links I visited seem to suggest that the answer is a sort of "yesno". In any case, I'll wait for the OP to add it to the answer.

Comment: @Alenanno “color as a tool” doesn’t directly address whether nebulae have colour (but does so indirectly, because “natural” and “enhanced” both use the natural colour information). However, the example “The Eagle Nebula” shows a clear case where the original visible light information is used to render the coloured representation. That’s not a “yesno”. It’s true that not all the colours represented in images correspond to colours in the visible spectrum of the object. But that doesn’t imply that the objects don’t have colour.

Comment: Added clarification about B&W images. BTW, I never took this question as "Do nebulae have color?" but as "Are the colors in the images "true" colors?"

Answer (score 10):

To the human eye, nebulae always appear overwhelmingly B&W. Human dark-adapted eyes are much more sensitive to B&W ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_%28eye%29)) and their color sensitivity shifts. There are only a few nebulae that are reliably visible to the naked eye and your pupil just can't pick up enough photons to detect color.

[This discussion of amateur astrophotography](http://www.astropix.com/HTML/I_ASTROP/DSLR_HA.HTM) breaks down the colors that you would be able to perceive with enough aperture: essentially there's a lot of very faint red up there (from hydrogen emissions) and there's some amount of relatively "bright" blue that's caused by scattering similar to what happens in our atmosphere during the day. You can reliably perceive blue nebulosity in, for instance, the Orion nebula with moderate amateur equipment. With exceptional equipment and conditions (a 24" Starmaster at 9000' on Mauna Kea) I've perceived faint red and green. Modern professional telescopes do not allow for direct visual observation :-( .